# Geckodriver Selenium Auto Download PDFs

Tags: selenium, geckodriver

I'm trying to automatically download .pdf files in geckodriver/Firefox.  I've searched on stackoverflow and other resources and think the code below should work:

```
profile.set_preference("browser.download.folderList", 2)
profile.set_preference("browser.download.manager.showWhenStarting", False)
profile.set_preference("browser.download.dir", 'C:\\Users\\xyz\\Downloads\\')
profile.set_preference("browser.helperApps.neverAsk.saveToDisk", "application/octet-stream,application/pdf,application/x-pdf,application/vnd.pdf")
profile.set_preference("pref.downloads.disable_button.edit_actions", True)
profile.set_preference("browser.helperApps.neverAsk.openFile", "application/octet-stream,application/pdf,application/x-pdf,application/vnd.pdf")
browser = webdriver.Firefox(firefox_profile=profile)
```

I also tried:

```
profile.set_preference("pdfjs.disabled", True)
```

However, Firefox does not automatically download the .pdf (even though it is application/pdf in the http req).  Also, after I load that profile in Firefox, under "Options / Applications", the PDF format still shows "Preview in Firefox" instead of "Save File"...  What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Try by adding the following preference also, to the existing list:

```
fp.setPreference("pdfjs.enabledCache.state", false);
fp.setPreference("browser.helperApps.neverAsk.openFile","application/pdf");
```

Answer (score 0):

To disable open and download pdf in firefox:

```
FirefoxOptions options = new FirefoxOptions();
options.addPreference("browser.download.folderList", 2);
options.addPreference("browser.download.dir", pathToDownload);
options.addPreference("browser.helperApps.neverAsk.saveToDisk", "application/pdf");
options.addPreference("pdfjs.enabledCache.state",false); 
WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver(options);
```

Comment: I added the preferences I did not have, and it still did not work unfortunately

Comment: Try profile.setPreference("browser.helperApps.alwaysAsk.force", false);

Comment: alwaysAsk.force is on the preferences above and it did not work.  Also, the content type is application/pdf so that's not the cause of the problem