# Why firefox downloads PDF file with name 'Document' instead of actual name from URL after configuring Firefox to download file without save as dialog?

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, firefox, geckodriver, selenium-firefoxdriver

```
        FirefoxOptions options = new FirefoxOptions();
        FirefoxProfile profile = new FirefoxProfile();

        // Accept Untrusted Certificates
        profile.setAcceptUntrustedCertificates(true);
        profile.setAssumeUntrustedCertificateIssuer(false);

        //Directly download PDF


        profile.setPreference("browser.helperApps.neverAsk.openFile", "application/pdf");
        profile.setPreference("browser.helperApps.neverAsk.saveToDisk", "application/pdf");
        profile.setPreference("pdfjs.disabled", true); // disable the built-in PDF viewer

        // Set Firefox profile to capabilities
        options.setCapability(FirefoxDriver.PROFILE, profile);
```

I have used above code to configure firefox so that it directly downloads the PDF when clicked on a PDF link using selenium webdriver. When an automation script clicks on a link that download the PDF, the script downloads the file directly **but it loses the original name but downloaded as 'Document'** refer attachment for screenshot of downloaded files.
[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Selenium problems with PDF download in Firefox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52208798/selenium-problems-with-pdf-download-in-firefox)

Answer (score 0):

The solution to this problem is [http download file name](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13307499/3092298) — the web server needs to send certain HTTP headers back to the client to set the file name. You won't fix this with a browser setting, or anything to do with Selenium.

Fixing this requires setting the `content-disposition` HTTP header in the response from the server. Something like this:

```
content-disposition: attachment; filename=TheFileNameYouWant.pdf
```

Comment: Hi Greg, Thanks for your reply. I need to point out that same link works fine in chrome. It gives proper name which URL has.
I see below header
HTTP/1.1 200 200
Date: Fri, 03 Apr 2020 05:46:47 GMT
Content-Disposition: inline; filename=MANDATE-REFERENCE000000000000000268.pdf
Keep-Alive: timeout=15, max=98
Connection: Keep-Alive
Content-Type: application/pdf
Transfer-Encoding: chunked

Comment: I checked Firefox manually as well (i.e. without preference set by selenium geckodriver.) The header contains content-disposition. Also, from about:config I  set pdfjs.disabled", true 
browser.helperApps.neverAsk.openFile", "application/pdf"
browser.helperApps.neverAsk.saveToDisk", "application/pdf"
then also it works fine.